# How to show full datalist dropdown list in Chrome?

Tags: html, google-chrome, html-datalist

I have a form and there I have a field of type text, I wanted it to have a suggestion list when the user types something in, I made it like this:

```
State: <br>
<input type="text" name="state" size="35" autocomplete="on" list="states" required> <br><br>

<datalist id="states">
<option value="Baden-Württemberg">
.....
</datalist>
```

So in the Test Browser of the software I use (CoffeeCup HTML Editor) and in the newest Internet Explorer it actually works, <del>but when I run this in Chrome it is just a simple textfield and has no dropdown list</del>
If I type the first letter of any of the elements, a list actually pops up, **but it would be nice to have a full list showing, like it does in IE.**

Do I have to do something special for chrome?

Chrome:

[image]

IE:

[image]

Comment: This is an auto-complete list (not a drop-down menu), so, as far as I know, in Chrome you need to press the down arrow, or start typing something that begins with the letters of the option. Or am I missing something here?

Comment: @shennan Even if I start typing or press down-arrow nothing happens :/

Comment: you have to put the carret in the textbox before any of this functionality takes place. With the code you gave (adding a closing `</option>` tag) it works fine for me. So please give full code because it is obviously something else stopping it from working.

Comment: @shennan Oh wait, I must apologize, if I type the first letter of one of the elements, it actually shows a list.
I just thought it could show the full list for the user, like it does in IE, I'll add screenshots for comparison.

Answer (score 1):

In recent versions of Chrome a downward triangle icon appears in the input on focus which allows you to see all suggestions. This is present in Chrome 42, I haven't checked older versions to see when this was implemented.

[image: Input with datalist suggestions featuring a down arrow icon]

Note that there is no scrolling in the suggestions list. If it exceeds the page it will overflow out of the browser and will continue even below the bottom of your screen with no method of reaching some of the values until you type more characters.

Comment: is there a fix to allow scrolling?

Comment: @madphp No. Chrome's datalist support is crap right now. It just renders the list straight off your screen without providing a scroll bar. If the list is too long it crashes Desktop Window Manager on Windows. It only provided results that start with, rather than contains the text that was typed. It's completely unusable as far as I am concerned. Mozilla's behavior is exactly what any sane individual would expect. There are several bug reports open for these issues, but don't hold your breath.